# Using string values in a list as integers and displaying them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

There is a class called Population which has the age of all the people (sample population) in string values. I have to create a function which shows the how many percentage of people fall into a particular interval of age. For example if the list is ["25","67","37","23","25","19","46","50"], the function **info** should display the percent of people in each age range when executed **info(population)**:

```
Number of people #8
<20's: 12.5%
20's: 37.5%
30's: 12.5%
40's: 12.5%
50's: 12.5%
more than 60's: 12.5%

Mean age:
```

I am having difficulty trying to use the numbers which are in string form and counting them as an int. How do I go forward with this, I'm quite confused. Also I can't use comprehended lists for this task.

The code has to follow this:

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self,age=None):
        self.age=age

p = Population()
p.age = [25,36]

def info(population):
    ???

info(p)
```

Comment: Iterate through the list, keep a counter of which ages are in the range, then return `counter / len(population)`. To convert a string to an integer, just do `int(string)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the ages to integers if you use a dictionary to keep track. Try this and see if it does what you are asking.

```
class Population:
    def __init__ (self, age_list = None) :
        self.age_list = age_list
        self.mean_dictionary = {
                '10': 0,
                "20": 0,
                "30": 0,
                "40": 0,
                "50": 0,
                "60": 0,
                "70": 0,
                "80": 0,
                "90": 0}
        self.show_information ()

    def show_information (self) :
        total = 0
        for age in self.age_list :
            key = str (age [0]) + '0' 
            self.mean_dictionary [key] += 1
            total += 1

        print (f"\nNumber of people {len (self.age_list)}")
        over_60_total = 0
        for age_group, count  in self.mean_dictionary.items () :
            percent = 100 * float (count) / float (total)
            if age_group <= '50' :
                print (f"{age_group}'s:  {percent}%")
            else :
                over_60_total += count
        percent = 100 * float (over_60_total) / float (total)
        print (f'60 and over: {percent}%')

p = Population (["25","67","37","23","25","19","46","50"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def info(population):
    int_ages = list(map(lambda age: int(age), population))
    return int_ages
```

Here's a simple way to turn all the string values from your list into integers so then you could use them to calculate the percentages.